# Why does list turn out different than expected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, compression

I have a list with integers. I then want to change the list so that instead of it containing, let's say four 1:s in a row, it shoudl say `[[4, 1]]`. So I made a function for that, but I get a unexpected result.

This is the function

```
compressed3 = []

def repeat_comp(data):
    rep = 1

    for i, item in enumerate(data):
        if i < len(data) - 1:
            if item == data[i + 1]:
                rep += 1

            else:
                compressed3.append([rep, data[i - 1]])
                rep = 1

        else:
            if item == data[i - 1]:
                rep += 1

            else:
                compressed3.append([rep, data[i - 1]])
                rep = 1

repeat_comp(compressed2)
```

This is the `compressed2` list

```
[0,
 1,
 2,
 3,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 1,
 4]
```

Here is the result of the function compared to the expected result

```
# output of function
[[1, 2832], # why this? (this number is one less than the lenght of another list that has nothing with this list to do)
 [1, 0],
 [1, 1],
 [1, 2],
# excluded value here
 [4, 1],
 [1, 1], # why this?
 [1, 4]]

# expected result
[[1, 0],
 [1, 1],
 [1, 2],
 [1, 3],
 [4, 1],
 [1, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to change two things in your code to get the expected results:

```
def repeat_comp(data):
    rep = 1
    compressed3 = []

    for i, item in enumerate(data):
        if i < len(data) - 1:
            if item == data[i + 1]:
                rep += 1

            else:
                compressed3.append([rep, item])
                rep = 1

        else:
            if item == data[i - 1]:
                rep += 1

            else:
                compressed3.append([rep, item])
                rep = 1
    return compressed3
```

Move the `compressed3` list into the function and let the function return it, so every time you call the function `compressed3` gets cleared. You can then assign the returned list to another variable:

```
result = repeat_comp(compressed2)
```

And I changed `data[i - 1]` to `item`

`print(result)` will give you `[[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [4, 1], [1, 4]]`

Answer (score 2):

This is a great illustration of why functions should be [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence#Computer_science_examples), that is, each invocation of the function should produce the same result given the same input. By moving the result list `compressed3` outside of the function, the caller is burdened with determining which calls mutate this global variable; almost inevitably, confusing results will occur.

I'd write the function as follows, using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def compress_runs(lst):
    return [[len(list(v)), k] for k, v in groupby(lst)]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(compress_runs([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6])) 
    # => [[3, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5], [1, 6]]
```